# I replaced old git versioned files in directory, what can i do?

Tags: git, github

I created _bak directory that was under version control (i renenamed it to project_bak) and after that i create new directory and copy files that was under git version control to new directory on same place.

But if i opened gitx, i dont see any changes in directory (i did same changes in file).

I think that git has some hidden files that i moved with project but i cannot show them on Mac os.
How  to solve it please?

Comment: is your new directory under version control? I recommend using names instead of "new directory" which is not very clear. What is the link between _bak and new directory?

Comment: No is not under vesion control, but has same structure. I copied files from directory, that is under control. And i thought, that everything will be as before. Link between _bak and new directory is not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The git repository is in a hidden folder called `.git` at the root folder of your project (`project_bak/.git`). You can access this folder normally by path in terminal, or open it in Finder by pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and typing in the full path.